# cut off data in a dump file

Tags: mysql

I am using **MySQL**.

I got a **mysql dump file** (large_data.sql), I can create a database and load data from this dump file to the created database. No problem on this.

Now, I feel **the data in the dump file is too large** (for example, it contains 300000 rows/objects in one table, other tables are also contain a large amount of data).

So, I decided to make another dump (based on the large size dump) which can contains a small size of data (for example, 30 rows/objects in a table).

With only that big size dump file, **what is the correct and efficient way** to cut off the data in that dump and create a new dump file which contains small amount of data?

------------------------- More -----------------------------------

(Use textual tool to open the large size dump is not good, since the dump is very large, it takes long time to open the dump from textual tool)

Comment: You'll have to manually edit it, or re-import the dump file and make new, shorter dumps (which however I think you need to do on a per-table basis by specifying a custom query.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work only on the textual dump files, you could use some textual tools (like `awk` or `sed`, or perhaps a `perl` or `python` or `ocaml` script) to handle them.

But maybe your big database was already loaded from the big dump file, and you want to work with [MySQL incremental backups](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/glossary.html#glos_incremental_backup)?

Comment: Use textual tool is not good, since the dump is very large, it takes time to open the dump from textual tool

Comment: You don't need to open the dump in an editor. I was suggesting to filter it (assuming a Unix system) with standard Posix or Unix utilities which, since they work line by line, are able to deal with very large input files (and read them in sequence).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend free file splitter : http://www.filesplitter.org/ .

Only problem : it cut a query in two parts. You need to edit manualy the file after but, it work like a charm.

Example :

My file is :

```
    BlaBloBluBlw
    BlaBloBluBlw
    BlaBloBluBlw
```

Result will be :
File 1:

```
    BlaBloBluBlw
    BlaBloBl
```

File 2:

```
    uBlw
    BlaBloBluBlw
```

So you need to edit everything but it work like a charm and very quick. Used today on a 9,5 millions rows table.

BUT !! Best argument : the time you will take to do this is small compared to the time you try to import something big or waiting for it... this is quick and efficent even if you need to edit the file manualy since you need to rebuild the last and first query.